# Can I use HSV colors inside a background_color parameter in python/kivy?

Tags: python, widget, kivy, background-color, hsv

I want to use HSV to define some Widget colors, I can do it easily the 'Color' module as in:

```
Color((1, 0, 0), mode = 'hsv')
```

But my question is, sometimes you want to be faster and more specific so is there a way to do the same or similar with the background_color parameter?
Almost needless to say I've tried and failed on this:

```
my_hsv_color = Color((0.5, 1, 0.6), mode='hsv')
my_button = Button(background_color = my_hsv_color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Color` is a class or better said, the thing that you pass to `background_color` is an instance of `Color` (object). The `background_color` requires a list/tuple or something else that's iterable.

`Color` i.e. class has such properties [right here](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Color.rgba) and since Kivy works with rgba in interval of `0.0 - 1.0`, you need to feed the property with `rgb` or `rgba`.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
Builder.load_string('''
#:import Color kivy.graphics.Color
<Test>:
    Button:
        background_color: tuple(Color(0.5, 1, 0.6, mode='hsv').rgba)
''')
class Test(BoxLayout): pass
runTouchApp(Test())
```

I even think you can use this kind of unpacking in Python 3:

```
background_color: *Color(0.5, 1, 0.6, mode='hsv').rgba
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. But using your code I come across another problem, whenever I try to access data from the .kv code as in:



`my_color = my_color_holder.ids.my_color_holderkv.background_color `


The Kivy opens the .exe file along with the .py file with a blank white screen, do you know how to work around it?

Comment: I think the reason is re-importing the `Color` in `.kv` file, which already _is_ imported, yet I don't see another window. Consider updating to 1.9.2 if you use the `stable`(1.9.1) version.

Answer (score 1):

Using KeyWeeUsr answer above I've come up with those two simple solutions to use HSV in the background_color paramater (Python 2.7):

An extended version:

```
with self.canvas:
        Rectangle(size = (250,250), background_color = tuple(Color(1,1,1, mode='hsv').rgba))
```

Or with a simple function:

```
def HSVtoRGB(color1,color2,color3):
    from kivy.graphics import Color
    return tuple(Color(color1, color2, color3, mode='hsv').rgba)
```

Using it like that:

```
with self.canvas:
        Ellipse(size = (250,250), background_color = HSVtoRGB(0.5,0.7,1)
```